# Calling a GLOBAL Jenkins Library from a function in a pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Given:

```
#!groovy

@Library('GreatUtils')
def utils = new com.X.Utils(script:this)

node {
    stage('Call utils.check directly') {
        utils.check()
    }
}
```

This code works, and the library `utils` is called.

```
#!groovy

@Library('GreatUtils')
def utils = new com.X.Utils(script:this)

node {
    stage('Call utils.check indirectly') {
        checkUtils()
    }
}

def checkUtils() {
    utils.check() << -- throws exception 
}
```

This throws -

> No such property: utils
>    for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens if you define the checkUtils() function before your node logic? e.g. place all your defs before node{...}

Comment: That didn't work, tried it :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In groovy function don't have access to variable declare outside of their scope, the error is simply because your variable `utils` is out of scope.

Passing it by parameter like this should work

```
#!groovy

@Library('GreatUtils')
def utils = new com.X.Utils(script:this)

node {
    stage('Call utils.check indirectly') {
        checkUtils(utils)
    }
}

def checkUtils(utils) {
    utils.check()
}
```

Or if you don't want to use parameter you could go for a functional programming style and use [Closures](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) like

```
#!groovy

@Library('GreatUtils')
def utils = new com.X.Utils(script:this)

def check = { -> utils.check() }
node {
    stage('Call utils.check indirectly') {
       check()
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Adding the Global initialization possibility.

```
#!groovy

@Library('GreatUtils')
utils = new com.X.Utils(script:this)

node {
    stage('Call utils.check indirectly') {
        checkUtils()
    }
}

def checkUtils() {
    utils.check()
}
```

Should work.

Comment: Another option (ugly in my opinion) is to make the variable "globally scoped" - instead of `def utils` just write `utils`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thanks for the info. But as you said global = ugly and is to be avoided when you can.

Comment: Baptiste, thanks - this works (closures are not an option tho). mkobit - your suggestion does not work, thanks tho...

Comment: Can't use closure because the library contains several methods and they all need to be called plus additional code - that's what private methods are for....

Comment: Now, I don't mind using a global to hold Utils, has anyone figured out how to do it - in essence, make what mkobit suggested work?

Comment: @Amir I have just tried my suggestion on a test project, and it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: It works, I added the solution with global initialization.

Comment: I forgot about another that might work, but using the [`@Field`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.12/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html) annotation _might_ work with Jenkins script compilation.